# Setting root in .NET MVC4 project to /app/index.html

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am using an MVC4 project, but am going to be using angularjs for the front end and the WebApi to serve up JSON.

Issue I have now is that I cannot figure out how to configure my website to treat /app/index.html as the root of the project.

I'm sure its something in the web.config, but cannot figure out how to force ISS to set this as the default.  I still need to be able to access /Api/  for my api calls.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Do you need a full MVC project if your not going to being using ASP.NET MVC?  If you have a solution with a web project and an API project, your web project should be able to be just a folder structure set up how Angular likes it.  You won't need the MVC routing engine, etc...

Comment: That is an option, if I can figure out how to get the web project to point to the /app folder instead of the /Controllers folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use a rewrite rule in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Default" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(?!api|images|Content|Views|Scripts|favicon|robots).*" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```